# Meaning of 근위 서울 류경수 제105땅크사단

Tags: north-korean

As I read from [this article](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%A0%9C105%EA%B8%B0%EA%B0%91%EC%82%AC%EB%8B%A8_(%EC%A1%B0%EC%84%A0%EB%AF%BC%EC%A3%BC%EC%A3%BC%EC%9D%98%EC%9D%B8%EB%AF%BC%EA%B3%B5%ED%99%94%EA%B5%AD)), this is the first division which reached the capital Seoul.

Can you please explain what means 근위 서울 류경수? Can it be translated just as guard Seoul? Does 류경수 mean armored?

Comment: FYI) 땅크 is 문화어(North-Korean standard) word of tank and it is originated from a Russian word танк. In 표준어(South-Korean standard) it is 탱크. Many loanwords of 문화어 are based on Russian, while loanwords of 표준어 are based on American English.

Comment: There are few loanwords in North from Russian. The vast majority of the non-chinese borrowings are from English, like in South. In many cases, they can be transcribed differently. 콤퓨터, 메터, 뻐스, 렌스 they are different in South.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

근위 (noun) : protecting something in close distance

근위 is not used in South Korea nowdays. 근위 is protecting
something in close distance. At a monarchial system, 근위병 is a
soldier protecting a king so that they are in more honorable
position than normal soldiers.

So North Korean gave to 류경수's army the word "근위" as a
**honorable title** for blessing their fight at Daejeon city.

Before a fight at Daejeon, the army entered into Seoul city so that
North Korea gave the title "서울" for blessing their attacking Seoul
city.

That is, 근위 서울 means two fine war records in time order.

Comment: So, 근위 is used instead of verb?

Comment: 근위 is a noun : Protecting a king in close distance. So 근위병 is soldiers potecting a king in close distance. Verb ? What do you mean ?

Comment: 근위 서울 means division, that protects Seoul?

Comment: How North Korea names their divisions(?) is anyone's guess, but I think 근위 & 서울 are two separate prefixes, not related to each other. (After all, Seoul is not a part of North Korea now. Any troops that can be named 근위-something should be around Pyongyang, if the term means anything.) Also the order is wrong - for example South Korean 수도(capital) 방위(defense) 사령부(command?) is written in this order, but "방위 수도" would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is directly translated like below.

근위 Royal (or Elite)

서울 Seoul (City of south korea)

류경수 Kyungsu-Ryu (Name of person)

제150 105th

땅크 Tank (Armored vehicle)

사단 Division

Comment: It is division name of North Korea, 105th Armored Division commanded by Kyungsu-Ryu entered Seoul at first. So it is gave honorable name 'Royal'(근위) and The commander Kyungsu-Ryu got honor that his name is attached to name of army division.